# Transactional commits in correct order and after commit hook with Spring Integration

Tags: transactions, spring-integration

These are all the requirements that need to be fulfilled

- The chain is wrapped in a transaction
- JMS transaction need to be committed at the end of the chain before the database transaction
- If a JMS commit fails, the database commits should not be executed
- After all successful database commits the message (with all its manipulations) need to be put on an output channel

The chain in question is the following

```
<int:poller id="myInputChannelPoller">
  <int:transactional transaction-manager="myTransactionManager">
</int:poller>

<int:chain id="myChain" input-channel="myInputChannel">
  <int:poller ref="myInputChannelPoller" />
  <int:service-activtor id="someMessageManipulation" />
  <int:service-activtor id="aDatabaseOperation" />
  <int:service-activtor id="sendJmsMessage" />
  <int:service-activtor id="anotherMessageManipulation" />
  <int:service-activtor id="anotherDatabaseOperation" />
</int:chain>
```

To wrap the chain in a transaction, I added the `<int:transactional/>` tag to the poller.

Having all the JMS transaction committed before the database transaction, I made use of the `ChainedTransactionManager`

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager myTransactionManager(JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager, JmsTransactionmanager jmsTransactionManager) {
        // jpa before jms, since the commits will be done in reverse order
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(jpaTransactionManager, jmsTransactionmanager)
}
```

This also ensures no database commits, when JMS commits fail.

The only requirement I'm not sure how to satisfy properly is the after database commit action. The first idea that came to mind was the `transaction-synchronization-factory` mechanism as in

```
<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="mySyncFactory">
  <int:after-commit channel="myOutputChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

and link it to the transaction of the existing poller

```
<int:poller id="myInputChannelPoller">
  <int:transactional transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" synchronization-factory="mySyncFactory">
</int:poller>
```

But this approach seems to send the message that was initially received from myInputChannel, not considering the message manipulations.

Another idea would be to add another `service-activator` `MyJpaTransactionManagerInjector` to the end of the chain, which adds the message and the output queue as payload to a subclass of JpaTransactionManager `MyJpaTransactionManager`.

Receive message and target output channel as input. Create a `ForwardMessage` and inject it to `MyJpaTransactionManager`.

```
public class MyJpaTransactionManagerInjector {

    @Inject
    private MyJpaTransactionManager myJpaTransactionManager;

    @ServiceActivator
    public void injectMessage(Message<?> message, @Header(value = "outputChannel") MessageChannel outputChannel) {
        myJpaTransactionManager.inject(new ForwardMessage(message, outputChannel));
    }
}
```

Register `ForwardMessage` before executing the commit.

```
public class MyJpaTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {

    private final ThreadLocal<List<TransactionSynchronizationAdapter>> synchronizations =
            new NamedThreadLocal<>("Transactional resources");

    public void inject(TransactionSynchronizationAdapter synchronization) {
        if (synchronizations.get() == null) {
            synchronizations.set(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        synchronizations.get().add(synchronization);
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareForCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status) {            
        super.prepareForCommit(status);
        if (synchronizations.get() != null) {
            synchronizations.get().forEach(TransactionSynchronizationManager::registerSynchronization);
        }
        synchronizations.remove();
    }
}
```

Forward message on `afterCommit()` to target channel

```
public class ForwardMessage extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {

    private Message<?> message;
    private MessageChannel outputChannel;

    public ForwardMessage(Message<?> message, MessageChannel outputChannel) {
        this.message = message;
        this.outputChannel = outputChannel;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCommit() {
        outputChannel.send(message);
    }
}
```

Whenever possible, I would avoid subclassing a `TransactionManager` since it's easy to break something that worked perfectly well. Is there a solution that should be preferred to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still stick with the `<int:transaction-synchronization-factory>`.

The `PollingConsumer` registers this:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(resource,
                                integrationSynchronization.getResourceHolder());
```

into the transaction.

Where `resource` is a `MessageChannel` for the consumer. In your case it is `myInputChannel` bean.

You can use something like:

```
IntegrationResourceHolder integrationResourceHolder = (IntegrationResourceHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(myInputChannel);
```

And call its `addAttribute()` to store the message after processing:

```
integrationResourceHolder.addAttribute("resultMessage", resultMessage);
```

Afterward you still can use that `<int:after-commit channel="myOutputChannel" />` and get access to that attribute via appropriate SpEL variable:

```
<int:after-commit channel="myOutputChannel"  expression="#resultMessage"/>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. It seems that ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronisationProcessor contains the logic you are mentioning. Checking the code I realised, that only the payload can be modified with the `expression` and the message headers will be taken from the message initially received from the input channel. So instead of `integrationResourceHolder.addAttribute` I ended up with `integrationResourceHolder.setMessage` which allows me to pass a message containing the modified payload as well as the modified headers.

Comment: Was checking the commit sequence again. Even with the use of `<int:transaction-synchronization-factory>` the `after-commit` execution happens directly after the first transaction manager (from the `ChainedTransactionManager` list) commits successfully. When the JpaTransactionManager follows (next in the `ChainedTransactionManager` list) and fails, the message has already been forwarded to the target channel. Maybe I don't use the `ChainedTransactionManager` as intended and need to switch to another approach. Is there a better way to synchronize JMS and JPA transactions with each other?

Comment: `JtaTransactionManager`?

Comment: Doesn't `JtaTransactionManager ` automatically mean XA transaction? In that case it would probably be an overkill.

Comment: Right, that is really about XA. Maybe you can form a separate SO question just related to the `ChainedTransactionManager` and the problem with synchronization? That already not related to the Spring Integration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. Since I wanted to avoid XA for performance reasons, I ended up using the `MyJpaTransactionManager` approach. I adapted the problem description to have the `MyJpaTransactionManager` code example thread safe.